# current_user_can() always returns true if user is super admin

Tags: multisite, admin, capabilities

`current_user_can('custom_capability')` always returns true for super admins even if the capability is explicitly denied as stated [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/). It does work with a normal admin account.

I have added a custom capability for users with a specific email address, which is set when new users are registered and on plugin activation.

```
if (!empty(get_super_admins())) {
    foreach (get_users(['login__in' => get_super_admins()]) as $user) {
        $user->add_cap('custom_capability', false);
    }
}

foreach (get_users(['search' => '*@specific-domain.com']) as $user) {
    $user->add_cap('custom_capability');
}
```

Checking a super admin profile without that specific email address correctly states `Denied: custom_capability` under the additional capabilities section of the profile.

The output of `wp_get_current_user()` if logged in with the same super admin account as above:

```
...

  ["caps"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["custom_capability"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["administrator"]=>
    bool(true)
  }

...
```

Nonetheless `current_user_can('custom_capability')` returns `true`.

Did anybody else ever have this issue? Am I overlooking something and this is intended behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation unfortunately not very clear on what "explicitly deny" actually entails. While setting a capability to `false` will normally explicitly deny the capability, that check is performed *after* super admins have been waved through. So even though the documentation says "unless explicitly denied", denying it this way doesn't work for super admins. Only the other roles.

The only way to explicitly deny a capability for a super admin is to use the `map_meta_cap` filter to return `do_not_allow` when the custom capability is checked.

The `map_meta_cap()` function, which the filter applies to, is quite complicated, but its basic purpose is to do things like translate `current_user_can( 'edit_post', 2 )` into either the `edit_posts` or `edit_others_posts` capability based on who the user is. Because `map_meta_cap()` is run before the super admin check, we can use this filter to explicitly return `do_not_allow` when checks for `current_user_can( 'custom_capability' )` are made for a super admin that doesn't have the capability. Here's some code to do that:

```
add_filter(
    'map_meta_cap',
    function( $caps, $cap, $user_id ) {
        /**
         * Only filter checks for custom_capability.
         */
        if ( 'custom_capability' === $cap ) {
            $user      = get_userdata( $user_id );
            $user_caps = $user->get_role_caps();

            /**
             * If the user does not have the capability, or it's denied, then
             * add do_not_allow.
             */
            if ( empty( $user_caps[$cap] ) ) {
                $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
            }
        }

        return $caps;
    },
    10,
    3
);
```

Comment: Awesome. Never thought the solution would come this fast. You might want to move the semicolon out of the 'do_not_allow ' string, though - other than that, this worked perfectly.